# Accessing a parameter of an object, within an arrow function

Tags: javascript, typeerror, arrow-functions

In the following code, the function MakeNode() returns a node, containing the arguments provided to MakeNode(). Within the node, there is a function, an arrow function that requires one of the variables of the node.

I have read the ES6 js doc regarding this. and scopes. Still can't find how my function can access the variable from its own object.

I Have tried accessing it these ways:

```
this.x
this.X
x
X
n.x
n.X
```

No success. Actual code:

```js
    function MakeNode(x, y) {
      let n =
      {
        Parent: null,
        X: x,
        Y: y,
        PrintXY: () => {
          console.log("X, Y =", x, y);
        }
      }
      return n;
    }
    
    //further, when called:
    var aNode = MakeNode(10, 20);
    aNode.PrintXY();
```

I expect the print statement to be

```
X, Y = 10 20
```

But i get:

```
X, Y = undefined undefined
```

I also get the following error, no matter what way i try to access it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined
```

Comment: Your actual code does exactly what you say you want. (Not that the object has anything to do with the variables you are accessing, its a simple closure).

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: @Quentin yeah, i just ran the code snipet and it seems to work. This must be explained by me not summarising every detail required for this example. The actual code is a little more complexe, but ill try giving more details, more pertinent lines of codes.

Comment: Always **test** your [mcve] to make sure they actually demonstrate the problem. Using a live demo is helpful for that.

Comment: You are right. this is my very first post. Should I remove the post and create another one when my minimal reproducible example will be more representative of my issue here?

Comment: No, fix the existing question. Destroying history and asking duplicate questions is looked on unfavourably (and can lead to a question ban)

Comment: Found it. I had variables declared in the wrong order, in a section of my code i hadn't touch in days. Some of these required others to be properly defined. Thank you for your help people, I will now close this question. Have a good day.